# How to make Android 2.2 app work in 2.1

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-manifest

Hi
I made an android app with 2.2 selected and API 8
Now how can I make it work in 2.1?
Is it possible to give support for 2.1 devices?
Or I have to develop all the app again from scratch? :-(
Hope not
Please kindly help me out
Thanking You
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your Android Manifest file, write:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion = "8"/>
```

this will support all phones wid OS 1.5,
if u want for 2.1, specify minSDK = 7.

Comment: `uses-sdk` by itself doesn't make your app runnable or compatible with earlier builds of Android - it just makes it installable. You still have to ensure that your code is compatible as per my answer. For example, try using android.app.backup on API level 7 or below - uses-sdk may let you install the app, but it will Force Close when you try to execute code from API level 8 or above. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 5):

You will need to change your manifest to flag your app for SDK 2.1, since that's how the Android Market filters apps that your device cannot run - without changing the uses-sdk value to a lower level, devices with Android 2.1 will never see your app in the Market, it's as simple as that.

Having said that, once you have done that, please read the Android Dev page on [backwards compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) - it has all you need to know about how to gracefully handle devices with a lower Android version that you would like.

The only additional development required is where your app is using an API 8 only feature, then you will need to put in the extra work to make it also compatible with lower API levels. Most of your code will likely remain unchanged.